# Countdown timer with hh:mm:ss format in Java

Tags: java, datetime-format

I have created a seconds countdown time program unfortunately I don't know how to convert it to hh:mm:ss format. I want to display it as hh:mm:ss on to the label I assigned it to. Just for the context, I have a database with this program where I can pull the seconds from the database. I want to pull the time format from the database though, but for some reason it won't work. I would really really appreciate it if you could help me with it.

Here's my code:

```
public class Event implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          int count = (int)(Double.parseDouble(tf.getText())); \\tf is a label where I display the seconds int data from my database
          timerLabel.setText(String.valueOf(count));
          TimeClass tc = new TimeClass(count);
          timer = new Timer(1000, tc);
          timer.start();
     }
}

public class TimeClass implements ActionListener {
   int counter;
   public TimeClass(int counter) {
         this.counter= counter;
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent tc) {
         counter--;
         if(counter >= 1) {
              timerLabel.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
         }
         else {
              timer.stop();
              timerLabel.setText("Done!");
              Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    long millis = 3600000;
    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
    System.out.println(hms);
}
```